# Django CSRF token missing in form submission despite including it

Tags: python, django, django-templates, csrf-token

I am working on a Django project where I have a form to verify a phone number using Twilio's API. However, I'm encountering an issue where the CSRF token is missing in the form submission, resulting in a "CSRF token missing" error.

I have already included the {% csrf_token %} template tag inside the  element in my HTML template. I have also verified that the django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware middleware is enabled in my Django settings.

```
@login_required
def verify_phone_number(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Code to initiate phone number verification using Twilio's API
        
        # Code to Return an HTTP response with the HTML content when verification request wasnt sent
        html_content = """
        return HttpResponse(html_content)
    else:
        # Return an HTTP response with the HTML content
        html_content = """
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Verify Phone Number</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Verify Your Phone Number</h1>

            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="phone_number">Phone Number:</label>
                <input type="text" id="phone_number" name="phone_number" required>
                <button type="submit">Verify</button>
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
        """
        return HttpResponse(html_content)
```

Comment: The `HttpResponse` probably does not render the passed html, so there is no CSRF token.

Comment: It's ugly to write html templates in views. Write them seperately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to render a template in order to use `{% csrf_token %}`. The way you do it, the actual string `{% csrf_token %}` will be in your HTML file instead of the Token field.

You need to put your HTML into a template file, then return a `TemplateResponse` for the template.

templates/verify.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Verify Phone Number</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Verify Your Phone Number</h1>

            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="phone_number">Phone Number:</label>
                <input type="text" id="phone_number" name="phone_number" required>
                <button type="submit">Verify</button>
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

and then change your code like so:

```
@login_required
def verify_phone_number(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Code to initiate phone number verification using Twilio's API
        
        # Code to Return an HTTP response with the HTML content when verification request wasnt sent
        return HttpResponse('')
    else:
        # Return an Template response with the HTML content
        return TemplateResponse(request, 'verify.html', {})
```

Comment: I have tried the approach using return render(request, 'verify_otp.html')

and I was getting template not found error.
TemplateDoesNotExist at /verify-phone-number/
verify_phone.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/verify-phone-number/
Django Version: 4.2.5
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: 
verify_phone.html
Exception Location: /Users/a/Documents/Code/E/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Raised during: LocalUser.views.verify_phone_number

Comment: In that case you need to check your template settings. Usually Templates are located in your app in the `templates` folder. Make sure, your template is located in there with no subfolders and named `verify_otp.html`. Then django should be able to find the template.
Also see this documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/templates/#support-for-template-engines
I would need to know more about your folder structure and template settings to help further.